# what makes java Collections a framework? (I don't see any 'inversion of control')

Tags: java, collections, frameworks, inversion-of-control

Google search gives me, 'The Collection in Java is a framework...'. Further search gives me, 'The key difference between a library and a framework is "Inversion of Control"'. I reckon in Collection's context, framework is not used in the sense of IoC. Please enlighten.

Comment: It's not a framework in that sense. It's a framework in the sense of a supporting structure.

Comment: Nah.  Those terms aren't nearly so well-defined, and there isn't a strong distinction as to which the collections in Java are.

Comment: "Java Collections Framework" might have been chosen simply to avoid the acronym colliding with ["Java Class library"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library), or something like that.

Comment: please provide a link for 'further search...".  The authority you are looking at for framework=IoC seems suspicious.  I'm not saying you, or they, are wrong, I'd just like to see the information in context.

Answer (score 1):

**The main difference between Library and Framework is:**

**Library**   =   Set of useful components

**Framework** =   Set of useful components + Utilities to use the components

---

**Library** is a set of reusable components.
It provides flexibility to the user on the way in which the components can be called or used.

**A real-world analogy of Library**:

Traditional City Taxi service is like a library.

Taxi can be called by waving hand, or by shouting 'Taxi...', or by calling a telephone number.

---

**Framework** is a Library that comes packaged along with some utilities for using the library.

Framework provides an extra benefit, by offering an efficient built-in way of using the components.

**A real-world analogy for framework:**
A Taxi service that comes with its own app is like a framework.
The Taxi cannot be called by waving hand or shouting 'Taxi...'.
Taxi can be booked only by using the app.

---

**Java Collections** is labeled as a framework, instead of as a library, because it comes with some useful implementations of algorithms (sorting, queue management, etc) along with the set of useful components (List, Set, HashMap, etc).

For example, Java Collections Framework provides an efficient built-in algorithm for sorting objects.

The programmer can choose to either use the built-in sorting utility or write a new algorithm.

As the built-in algorithms are provided along with components, Java Collections is considered a framework, rather than just a library.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the term "framework" is used anywhere near consistently enough to be tied down like this.

Answer (score 0):

A "framework" doesn't imply IoC.

The term is not well-defined, proven by the fact that you can find different definitions online.

E.g. [techterms.com](https://techterms.com/definition/framework) says:

> A framework, or software framework, is a platform for developing software applications. **It provides a foundation on which software developers can build programs for a specific platform.** For example, a framework may include predefined classes and functions that can be used to process input, manage hardware devices, and interact with system software. This streamlines the development process since programmers don't need to reinvent the wheel each time they develop a new application.

The "Java Collections Framework" is a good "foundation for building programs". That's all it means.